# Determine used npm package version in a react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

In my `package.json` file from my react app I have multiple entries in my dependencies with "Compatible with version" (circumflex symbol) like `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",` or `"axios": "^0.20.0",`.

Through the "compatible with version" flag `^version` on every `npm install` I have allowed npm to update and use an updated version of the given npm package like described here [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json).

So now in my package.json is still something like `"axios": "^0.20.0",`.

How can I determine which version a built react (via `npm run build`) and a develop react app (via `npm run start`) is using now while running?

Comment: The version of package installed will be present in package-lock.json

Comment: Do you want to know which react version you're using ?